apache skywalking java agent trace changes
I have a simplified project reflecting the problem here
The bottom line is this: there is a producer who puts a message in RabbitMQ, there is a consumer who consumes the message from there and processes it.
In the skywalking trace, it can be seen that the trace does not change (and I manually checked it by logging the sw8 headers). I.e., we put the message in a queue with a header, it also lies in the rabbit with a header, consumed with the same header, and when we start processing (in my simplified case, we create an entity based on the message and save) the traceId is changing.
What I want: to see the entire path in the trace, starting from the request in the producer service, ending with saving in the consumer service.
What I have now: the first trace to read from the queue (including reading), the second trace processing.
I am sure that the span should change, not the trace. Where did I mess up?
produce & consume
processing
